# Efficient Searching in Outlook mail box

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin

I have outlook 2011 in my mac. I have more than 30,000 emails in my mail box and would like to search from all the mails based on inputs.

Now using Advanced find I can do that , But for each and every value I have to add a new search criteria

eg .  Subject contains  xxx 
      Subject contains  yyy 
      Subject contains  zzz

it would be very difficult for me to add the search value manually if I have 1000 values to search for. 
Is there any effective way to do this or do we some plugin which would read from input file and populate these vales ?

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can get little bit help from this -- http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/finding-the-hidden-search-options-in-outlook-2011/ , also this one too - https://www.gvsu.edu/cms3/assets/428A2C9A-0FB7-5B0C-BBFCF723C12E59E3/outlook_mac_search_email.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In Windows version of Outlook there is a hidden tab that can be enabled by creating a new registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software \Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\QueryBuilder.` See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc513841%28v=office.12%29.aspx#SearchingOutlookData_OutlookQueryLanguages) (sroll to Building DASL Queries).

This adds SQL tab to *Filter* dialog of *Customize Current View*. Here you can write a text with DASL query. The query for your example would look like this:

```
("urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" LIKE '%xxx%' AND 
 "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" LIKE '%yyy%' AND 
 "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" LIKE '%zzz%')
```

You can create script that takes all keywords from a text file and formats them like

```
 "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" LIKE '%MyKeyword%'
```

and construct the DASL query prorgamatically from a text file. You can store your generated queries as text files and copy them in the SQL tab as necessary.

This solution is surely far from perfect but it is relatively easy to implement. The problem is that I do not know how to enable that tab in Outlook 2011 on Mac nor whether it is possible at all. I do not have a Mac so take this rather as a hint.